# how to add JS to this code so it will automatically slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do i make this automatically slide?
I've already made it so you can manually slide them, but i want them moving at the same time.

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

    if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
};
```

Comment: Could you please put this in a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to make it work.

```
var slideIndex = 1;
    $(function () {
        automaticSlider();
    })

    function automaticSlider() {
        showSlides(slideIndex);
        setInterval(function () { automaticSlider(); }, 1000) // 1000 is 1 sec before calling next slide.
    }

function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

    if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
};
```

Calling the function automaticSlider() at load, and then set interval is call it  automaticSlider() function after 1 sec. you can increase the time as per your convince.

Comment: `slideIndex` is undefinded in your example and the index is not getting incremented or decremented.

Comment: Did not added whole code till then, But now is !! Updated the code.

Comment: if this solves your error, please mark this as a answer @Valeriadg